# What do 'self' and 'new' mean in Ruby from Java perspective?

Tags: java, ruby, oop

I'm looking over some open-source code and can't wrap my head around this snippet.

```
class Something
    def self.smart
       new.smart
    end

    def smart 
      "test"
    end
end

class Other < Something

println Other.smart
```

Is the code trying to instantiate a new instance every time `smart` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def self.smart
       new.smart
end
```

is equivalent to `static` method, which can e accessed by using class name.

```
... static ... smart()
```

and

```
def smart 
      "test"
end
```

is equivalent to `instance` method, need object to access

```
... smart()
```

new is same as the in java, created an instance of class.

and the whole thing is equivalent to.

```
public static .... smart(){
   new ClassName().smart();
}
```